# Add new info by AJAX call - get callback by json or html?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, performance

I have an ajax call in order to get some new information, I want to know what is the right way to add new elemets into the dom.

By build the callback in the PHP and echo it out,
or send a json object to the script and build the div with the new info?

In your answer please include performance, speed of the results to show, server bandwidth costs.

Thanks!

Comment: Without code or size or type of information this question is impossible to answer correctly. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is the most compact object representation, and would have better network performance/efficiency to send than HTML.

Also, letting the front end JS code have knowledge of the "data" and not just its presentation, would allow you to be more flexible in executing client-side logic.

Also, this is a better separation of data, business logic, and presentation.  If you change your HTML/CSS, you shouldn't have to change the back end script that is only responsible for sending the data.

As far as DOM insertion, a good performance trick is to minimize the number of DOM insertions.  If your data includes 1,000 elements, instead of inserting them individually first iterate through them to build an HTML string, then wrap that string with a containing element and you can add it to the DOM with just one insertion.

Comment: Thanks you very much!, this is exactly what I did, just wanted to be sure that this is the very right way.